# How to center an element

Tags: c#, razor, blazor-webassembly, radzen

I've started learning Blazor with Radzen and want to center horizontally a Radzen element on the page. I understood, the only way to do that is to apply inline CSS to an element's property but what specific CSS should I write? Do I use some Bootstrap classes (where to find a list of what I can use?) or should I use plain classic CSS?

```
<RadzenMenu>
    <RadzenMenuItem Text="General" Path="/" Icon="home">
    </RadzenMenuItem>
</RadzenMenu>

@code {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though it's not very related to blazor or radzen,

Bootstrap classes : d-flex, justify-content-center
( ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex )

CSS: display: flex;
justify-content: center;